# Rapidly rising land after rain seen in India? What can cause this?

Tags: geology, rain

I came across a video where a piece of land was seen rising very rapidly after rain. The land got elevated within a few minutes by atleast a meter.
Can anyone suggest possible mechanisms?

I am sharing complete video link through my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZKVahlYXxcMqxwRsyP2JcHrAik2diYGG?usp=sharing).
A clipped part of it is also available here [on you tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezL7_FW36as)

Comment: [No success on the upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLMy2.png)

Comment: If you came across the video, why can't you share where you came across it?  There may be some concern about viruses otherwise...

Comment: Some drought affected land can swell when re-hydrated.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I got this video on WhatsApp so shared it like this. I have  updated the links now, please check.

Comment: @Fred can you explain in bit more detail, how it happens. Why it swells, why suddenly at this rate, and why this phenomenon is localized to a small area only?  Or could you please share some document where it is explained.

Comment: Probably expansion of a clay layer, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansive_clay

Comment: I'm not convinced this video is genuine.  To my eye, during the emergence of the mud the video has several different focal lengths, blurring at the boundaries between physical components, and the water runoff looks more like changes to layer masks.  OTOH they might all just be compression artifacts from a low-res phone camera.

Comment: @Jean-Marie Prival  I know clay expansion which creats problem in borehole as well as in geotechnical engineering projects. I am  concerned about its  fast rate and localized nature is what made it abnormal to me. My knowledge about this phenomen is more bookish that is why I posted this que. So swelling clay at this fast rate  to such height and confined to small area is  common in field?

Comment: @Deditos some of my colleagues confirm this vedio is genuine.

Comment: I have no field experience of such an extreme case, only theoretical knowledge like you. I just thought it could be the cause.

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival Suggest you write it up. Seems good enough for me to upvote

Comment: @Amartya.  Ah yes, there are clearer videos of the same incident on YT.  I agree with your points about this being unusual - it's not my area, but don't expansive soils swell over hours/days rather than seconds?  It looks more like some sort of land slip being pushed towards the viewer.